# why optimization breaks this C code?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, volatile

Does anyone see why -O2 breaks this code? I suspect it is a bug in gcc, as it works fine with on different platforms and with different versions of gcc. However, it is also possible that the code contains some peculiarity which I am not aware of. Could anyone enlighten me?

Here is the code, it is an implementation of a variable number of nested loops producing all possible combinations. The expected output is

```
100 1
010 2
001 4
110 3
101 5
```

and the broken version reports

```
100 1
010 2
001 4
100 1
010 2
```

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int nmax = 5; // finish after 5 combinations
    int n = 3;    // three elements
    int *out = (int*) calloc(nmax, sizeof(int)); 
    int *cnt = (int*) calloc(n, sizeof(int)); // declaring volatile solves the problem. But why ?
    int il, nl, i = 0;
    for (nl=1; nl<=n; nl++)
    {
        for (il=0; il<nl; il++) cnt[il] = 0;
        cnt[nl-1] = -1;
        while ( cnt[0]<n-nl )
        {
            for (il=nl-1; il>=0; il--)
            {
                if ( ++cnt[il] < n-nl+il+1 ) break;
                cnt[il] = 0;
            }
            for (il=1; il<nl; il++)
            {
                if ( cnt[il] <= cnt[il-1] ) cnt[il] = cnt[il-1]+1;
            }
            for (il=0; il<nl; il++) out[i] |= 1<<cnt[il];
            if ( ++i >= nmax ) break;
        }
        if ( i >= nmax ) break;
    }
    for (i=0; i<nmax; i++)
    {
       for (il=0; il<n; il++) printf("%d", out[i]&(1<<il) ? 1 : 0);
       printf("\t%d\n", out[i]);
    }
    free(cnt);
    free(out);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: which version of gcc are you using? Works fine with -O2 here with 4.7.2 (on x86)

Comment: Probably, you have some undefined behavior in your code. The last think I'd think, when I have such problem, is compiler bug.

Comment: Works both unoptimized and -O2 with gcc 4.4.6 on a 64-bit machine compiled both as i686 and x86_64. Running it through valgrind's memcheck tool didn't turn up anything.

Comment: AAARGH! why do these i,l,1 look so similar!! my head is spinning just trying to read this code-snippet :) :)

Comment: Ok. One quick solution to find out "**why**" is to objdump -S the two versions of the code(with and without volatile) and then diff the two. You will get to see **exactly** what gcc is thinking and you can pick up the rest from there...

Comment: @KirilKirov The program does not have undefined behavior (if it has, you can file a bug report against the static analyzer I work on).

Comment: @PascalCuoq - it's possible. Mine was just a guess, I didn't look deeply enough on the code. That's why I just added a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @KirilKirov I wouldn't trust myself to tell by reading the code or even executing it. That's why I wrote the static analyzer :)

Comment: @PascalCuoq - is it available in the internet and is it open source? I'm just curios:) (@OP sorry for the spam)

Comment: @KirilKirov Here is the verification of the program: http://pastebin.com/XNdZLEYV . It is easy in this case because the program is deterministic and has no inputs. If you are using a recent Debian or Ubuntu, you can obtain the static analyzer with "apt-get install frama-c"

Comment: @PascalCuoq determining if a program has undefined behaviour requires solving the halting problem , so I presume your analyzer has some other limits you haven't mentioned.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The program at http://pastebin.com/XNdZLEYV has for state `ina, outa, nmax, n, il, nl, i` for a total of 32 * 14 bits if I am not mistaken, so that particular program is more like a finite automaton with a number of states at most 2^(32 * 14) times the number of program points, nothing undecidable. Otherwise, you are right, there are limits; for instance, there may be false positives.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The “difficulty to predict things about software” (I prefer to reserve “undecidability” for Turing machines only. It is too easy to argue that all C programs are finite automata) does not prevent a static analyzer to be “sound” (never failing to warn about an undefined behavior): a simple workaround is to warn anytime it is difficult to conclude that undefined behavior is absent. Being sound and usably precise (not having too many false positives) is fundamentally difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You should post details of exactly which gcc version you're using, the target, and the exact command line you're using.  Additionally, posting the assembly generated by GCC (for example, by using the `-S` option) would be helpful.

I'm guessing that the compiler is incorrectly hoisting `cnt[0]` out of the `while` loop controlling expression.  The following modification (which would simulate the hoist) produces your incorrect output:

```
// ...

for (nl=1; nl<=n; nl++)
{
    int tmp;                            // <== new line
    for (il=0; il<nl; il++) cnt[il] = 0;
    cnt[nl-1] = -1;
    tmp = cnt[0];                       // <== new line
    while ( /*cnt[0] */ tmp <n-nl )     // modified
    {
        for (il=nl-1; il>=0; il--)

// ...
```

Of course, this is just a guess - it would be more interesting to get the requested details so the generated code could be examined.